# The best algorithm to simulate Block Drop

Tags: c, algorithm

Here is a demo image :

[image]

There are 8x8 blocks with some random red blocks in it. When user select them out, all the blocks above them will drop. I want to find a best way to simulate this with minor complexity.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
     if (currentBlock == blank) {
        while((currentBlock.pos.x - 8) >= 0) {
           aboveBlock = (currentBlock.pos.x - 8);
           replace(currentBlock,aboveBlock);
        }
     }
```

But I think it's not a perfect algorithm at all. Who can help me? Please. Thank you very much.

Comment: please add a relevant language too since the answers may be dependent on them.

Comment: @Koushik Well, he's looking for a general algorithm, nothing more. He might be able to easily translate that into his language of choice. If an answer uses a language he doesn't understand or whose concepts don't carry over into his language of choice, then that would be the time for narrowing his search. By the way, are you sure this is *C*, does *C* allow for variable declarations in loop headers (might be, not sure about that)?

Comment: @ChristianRau yes c99 and above allow that kind of declaration. and that is why i was asking him so(thinking he might be looking in the same language). well c++ is also a match(dont know about java) and there might be tricks in each of them to get a better solution so thats why suggested and also a lot more people might be able to access this question. but you are right he asked for an algorithm. i'l remove the tag if he feels its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you can carry over the position of all the blocks removed, you can avoid iterating over all the playing field to find where you need to drop.

Also, you can implement a recursive method that calls itself on the upper position until it hits the top.

```
//Called on an empty block
Drop(int x, int y) {
    if (y > 0) {
        aboveBlock = (currentBlock.pos.x - 8)
        replace(currentBlock,aboveBlock);
        Drop(x,y-1);
    }
}
```

Just call `Drop()` on the bottommost possitions cleared by the player move

Answer (score 0):

1) low level approach with as little moving as possible?
Keep one read pointer and one write pointer. Move data from read to write only when there has been blank elements. (Reverse the order of the indices [y][x] vs [x][y] if necessary).

```
Y = 0; // index for reading
y = 0; // index for writing
while (Y < height) {
    if (block[x][Y] == blank) { Y++; continue; }
    if (Y > y) block[x][y] = block[x][Y];
    Y++; y++;
}
// At this point the source ptr/index 'y' can lag behind -- clear the rest 
while (y < height) block[x][y++] = blank;
```

1b) this can be improved a bit by keeping track of the minimum index 'y' of the deleted block and/or skipping the uneffected columns.

2) high level approach: sort each column with qsort.